# What is happening in the background when a user upvotes?

Tags: support, voting, architecture

I was interested in how the [votes are being calculated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200358/how-votes-are-being-calculated-in-stackoverflow), and understanding the fact that most probably the vote count is stored in the posts table, raised a new and more important question to me. What happens when a user up-votes?

Assuming that updating the Posts table and adding new record into the Votes table will be "expensive", I wonder how SO designed this to work. Does the result get updated in the cache and/or pushed into some queue, and then updated in the background? Could you please share some details on the actual implementation.

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126942/152859) give enough details? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks for the link. That was indeed helpful. But actually in addition to what was described there I need more details on what information is cached and what queries are sent to DB when user opens a question/post.  Overall reputation and question score are clear . My question concerns the situation when a user opens a question it show whether user has voted for that question or not and how does it determines that ? Does it execute a DB query or that info is somehow cached. And when a user votes for q question how those requests are being processed ?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I will continue here... the link you have provided gave a hint that somewhere a queue is being used, but still it was not clear...

Answer (score 8):

tldr; An HttpModule and a socket give the page that "live" feel (not to mention some badass hardware)

A **lot** of stuff is happening.

Before you even load the page, a lot is going on. You get to enjoy subscribing to an activity monitor while on the page so that everything feels "live". This is done through an HttpModule using MiniProfiler.

When your request is all set up, and the page begins to load, the structure is sent from the server verbatim-*ish* (some js involved).

Your voting is queried from the database while the response is built (this is copy pasted from the source of this page at the time of writing this answer)

```
StackExchange.ready(function () {
        StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {
            StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');
        });


        StackExchange.question.init({hasOpenBounty:true,votesCast:[],canViewVoteCounts:true,totalCommentCount:3,shownCommentCount:3,highlightColor:'#DAD6B8',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:200396});

        styleCode();

            StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToQuestion('4', '200396');

                });
```

, and almost all activity is monitored through websockets if you support them.

```
    StackExchange.ready(function () {
        StackExchange.realtime.init('ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com');
        StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToInboxNotifications();
                StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToReputationNotifications('4');
            });
```

When you vote, your activity triggers this code-*ish* (source may be out of date)

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route(@"vote/{querySetId:\d+}")]
    public ActionResult Vote(int querySetId, string voteType)
    {
        if (Current.User.IsAnonymous)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }

        if (voteType == "favorite")
        {
            QuerySet querySet = Current.DB.QuerySets.Get(querySetId);

            if (querySet == null)
            {
                return Json(new { error = true });
            }

            Vote vote = Current.DB.Query<Vote>(@"
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    Votes
                WHERE
                    VoteTypeId = @vote AND
                    QuerySetId = @querySetId AND
                    UserId = @user"
                ,
                new
                {
                    vote = (int)VoteType.Favorite,
                    querySetId = querySetId,
                    user = CurrentUser.Id
                }
            ).FirstOrDefault();

            if (vote == null)
            {
                Current.DB.Votes.Insert(new 
                {
                    QuerySetId = querySetId,
                    UserId = CurrentUser.Id,
                    VoteTypeId = (int)VoteType.Favorite,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Current.DB.Execute("DELETE Votes WHERE Id = @id", new { id = vote.Id });
            }

            Current.DB.Execute(@"
                UPDATE
                    QuerySets
                SET
                    Votes = Votes + @change
                WHERE
                    Id = @id",
                new
                {
                    change = vote == null ? 1 : -1,
                    id = querySetId
                }
            );
        }

        return Json(new {success = true});
    }
```

The push of data from the server is handled by the socket and then you see the update live. That is pretty much what happens as far as I can tell. I do not have enough access to say for sure, and I am also not sure if this code is the code being used in production.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sir :). Although I can see how this can be a working solution still one thing bothers me...I can not convince myself to believe that when a user opens a question so many requests are being sent to DB. From your answer looks like when an authenticated user opens a questions aside from retrieving post with answers, comments, users reputation and etc there is also a request sent to check whether user has voted for the post...And moreover when a user votes at least one update/delete/insert happens...This looks really heavy, what about caching ? AFAIK SO uses redis ?

Comment: @Travis J Sorry don't want to sound arrogant, but based on the link below I doubt that is the way you have described. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how

Comment: @NDeveloper I didn't talk about caching. Mostly because of how complex it is.They cache a lot of content, and especially execution plans of queries.Almost everything attempts to defer to the cache, and there are many checks to see if the cache has been purged to ensure the data is relevant.I felt the explanation of caching with regards to actual code implemented would have been far too involved so I largely skipped over it.I mostly addressed the mechanism involved for querying votes, and the listener which covers the live vote updating.Live data is always new, and does not come from the cache.